# Flyway previous migration changed

Tags: flyway

Here's my workflow:

```
Setup tables, constraints etc. in V1__CreateSchema.sql (checksum = 
c3a82bcf43b3c78a5ca4ebd25ca06005)
```

Run flyway migration --> database gets created.

Then I realize that the schema needs to be updated:

```
Update sql statements in V1__CreateSchema.sql (checksum =   
   7e1aeb51d4e91b504cd920ec7af17092)
```

Run flyway migration --> flyway ignores the fact that a previously run migration's signature has changed.

```
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:2.3:migrate (default-cli) @ zeus ---
[INFO] Current version of schema `mydb`: 1
[INFO] Schema `mydb` is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

Is this a supported workflow? I would expect flyway to fail stating that a fork has been made in the past migration path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `flyway.validateOnMigrate` to `true` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

As per the question, It looks like you are using `flyway-maven-plugin`. Flyway maven plugin is supporting basic commands which could be used with flyway execution.

```
Here is the list of commands which are applicable to run with plugin.

 1. Migrate
 2. Validate
 3. Info
 4. Clean
 5. Baseline
 6. Repair

Example: mvn flyway:command_name
```

Now, let's say if we would like to confirm that current classpath schemas are changed or not from the previous versions then we could validate it by executing below command

> **mvn flyway:validate**

Apart from this, Configure or add the property named with `validateOnMigrate` to `true` at your flyway properties.